# modifying an existing access token permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've got an facebook application which is using an access token to set/get posts from facebook.
I want to add a new permission to this access token, is there any way i can do so?
(i want to add the rsvp_event permission)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add permissions to an existing token, because the users need to accept them.

So you need to ask for a new token with this additional permission, and your users will need to accept it before you get the new generated token.

Comment: Maybe i have forgot something, but when i make a new access token, posts are made by me instead of my page, any ideas? i tried to debug the token and i see that on my old one has a profile ID parameter in addition to all the other parameters, while the new one doesnt.

Comment: Did you actually generate a Page token? ([see here for Page tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/))